# Is the "When an HTTP request is received" trigger in PowerAutomate secure?

Tags: excel, vba, http, https, power-automate

Currently i am sending an HTTP post to power automate with https://vba-tools.github.io/VBA-Web/

I know anyone can trigger the flow if they know the URL however that is not what worries me.

I am concerned with the security of the data in transit.
The generated URL is https however the connector is called HTTP which makes me unsure if it is secure.

I havent been able to find anything in the documentation about this. Other than potentially adding an extra header to limit who can trigger the flow.

The generated URL looks like this.
`https://prod-21.westus.logic.azure.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check in Chrome tells me it's secure.  The lock is there and Chrome states very clearly that it's secure.

[image: URL]

Microsoft aren't going to allow a non-secured endpoint without being very explicit and in my limited knowledge, I would think if the URL is http**s** then  anything backend related would need ensure that it conforms and is secure.